# What should I include in my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application's program.cs?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I've migrated an ASP.NET MVC application to .NET 6 and notice that during testing, the arguments to an action method/controller uses query string rather than the usual REST-style URL.

For example, where the existing ASP.NET MVC 4 application would use the following style of URL

```
http://webserver/controller/action/123
```

the migrated web application uses

```
http://webserver/controller/action?id=123
```

I created the migrated app from scratch using the template for an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application.

The `program.cs` is as follows:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    // doesn't affect the app if it isn't hosted on IIS
    builder.WebHost.UseIIS();
    builder.WebHost.UseIISIntegration();

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => 
    {
        // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    });

    builder.Services
        .AddControllers()
        .AddMvcOptions(opts =>
        {
            opts.MaxModelBindingCollectionSize = 10000;
        });

    builder.Services
        .AddRazorPages()
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    try
    {
        Log.Information("Application starting up");
        app.Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Application startup failed");
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

The Home view renders links to the other controllers using Html helpers such as

```
@Html.ActionLink("Vendors", "Index", "VendorController", new { @Id = 15153, @Code = "AGR3" }, null)
```

and the VendorController action method is

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int id, string code)
{
    // model is a POCO class
    var model = _dataService.GetVendorInfo(id, code);

    return View("Index", model);
}
```

How do I get my migrated ASP.NET Core MVC application to not use query string for passing arguments?  Do I need to decorate the action method with some kind of routing attribute?  I thought I could rely on convention-based routing as per the route pattern declared in the call to `app.UseEndpoint` in the Main() method of Program.cs?

Comment: Can you please add example of the controller which does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asp.net core,you could regist mutipule route patterns

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "myfirstroute",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}/{Code?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "mysecondroute",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
```

Specific the name of the route parttern with `asp-route` and add the required routedata as below(if your dictionary contains the key-values pairs whose key was not registed  as a section in your route pattern,it would be added to the query part)

```
@{
    var routedatadic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    routedatadic.Add("controller", "Vendor");
    routedatadic.Add("action", "Index");
    routedatadic.Add("id", "123");
    routedatadic.Add("Code", "ABC");
}

<a  asp-route="myfirstroute" asp-all-route-data="@routedatadic">Vendor1</a>

<a  asp-route="mysecondroute" asp-all-route-data="@routedatadic">Vendor2</a>
```

The result:
[image]

You could check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0) related

Comment: Thanks @RuikaiFeng for such a good answer, there seems to be little about MVC for ASPNET Core out there, all the articles and docs I've come across so far focus on Razor pages rather than MVC